# Wordpress - overwrite css index class?

Tags: css, wordpress, class, indexing, edit

I would like to edit a separation section on my website to remove an empty space below it, nothing too fancy just basically going from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Seemed pretty easy to me but when I went looking for the css file to edit that class I couldn't find it, the editor tells me it is the (index) file located at the root of the website but I don't have such css file in there.

Any help on where to add the missing line?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Worked! Thanks @KirkBeard

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.page .page-wrap .content-wrapper{

    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

If doesn't work reply with website URL.